# JVMUtil class not found when attempting to use JOGL Swing test code

Tags: java, eclipse, jogl

When I try to run the [JOGL Swing test code](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_AWT_SWT_and_Swing#JOGL_in_Swing), I get an error message saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/nativewindow/impl/jvm/JVMUtil
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:625)
    at com.jojodmo.wizardgame.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.nativewindow.impl.jvm.JVMUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Line 34 of my `Main.java` has this line, where `GLProfile` is `javax.media.opengl.GLProfile`:

```
GLProfile glprofile = GLProfile.getDefault()
```

and is the first time that I do anything with JOGL in the file. I'm using [JOGL 2.0](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-2.0-beta10/), and the file I'm using is called `jogl-2.0-macosx-universal.zip` (I've also tried using [version 1.1.1](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-1.1.1/), but get the same result, on top of the fact that its outdated). It's downloaded from [java.net](http://java.net), which isn't official, and may be the problem, but I'm not sure.

I'm importing both the `gluegen-rt.jar` and `jogl.all.jar` into eclipse:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEple.png]

and I'm setting the `Native library location` to the folder that contains the `.jnilib` and `.so` files:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEple.png]

Is the problem that I'm using `swing` with `awt`, or is it some other error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict with JOGL 1, please uninstall it, remove it from your JVM and/or from the directories used by the extension mechanism. "com/sun" is no longer present in JOGL 2.3.1 (currently, June 2015). JOGL 2.0 is obsolete, jogl.all.jar has been renamed jogl-all.jar in the meantime. Please follow our instructions available on our Wiki:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE

P.S: Oracle abandoned JOGL in November 2009, it has been very actively maintained by the JogAmp community. I'm responsible for engine support.